# How to store a string variable and use it in any other Angular 6 component?

Tags: angular

For example, I have my log-in component and the main app-component which contains my navbar. I want that whenever a user logs in successfully, send the username to the app-component, and instead of diplaying in the navbar "Sign In", display the username sent from my log-in component.

Comment: Can you please show your effort, what you have tried so far?

Comment: write a service for storing and retrieving  those values in local storage, use that service in both components.

Answer (score 1):

You need to achieve this using BehaviorSubject.

**service.ts**

```
private username = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
public username$ = this.username.asObservable();

updateUsername(username: string){
   this.username.next(username);
}
```

**Login Component:**

On login success, call the service and send the username

```
service.updateUsername('login user');
```

**NavBar Component:**

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.service.username$.subscribe((username)=>{
     // username
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a **BehaviorSubject** for that.

Let's say you have a service called  **UserService**. In UserService
create a instance of BehaviorSubject.

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
```

In order to listen to the changes in *currentUserSubject* that we created, we change it into observable using asObservable().

```
public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
```

In **LoginComponent** , inject the UserService dependency and emit the data that you get form successful login.

```
constructor(private userService:UserService){}

login(){
 //make api call
 //if successful login, then emit the user data returned from API call
   this.userService.currentUserSubject.next("value we want to emit.");
}
```

All the subscribers to the *currentUser* Observable will be notofied about the changes in currentUserSubject. You can subscribe to this observable in your **NavBarComponent** like this.

```
constructor(private userService:UserService){}
OnInit(){
 this.userService.currentUser.subscribe((value)=>{
   console.log(value);//value emitted from observable.
 })
}
```